# How to track the number of Celery requests completed for a certain user within Redis?

Tags: python, redis, celery

My idea is to allow many users to make a large post request to one instance. Assuming that the instance is configured to handle one instance at a time, I use Celery with Redis as a message broker to complete everyone's task asynchronously although taking some time.

My question is how do I view or keep track of how many of a certain user's task is completed? For example if person A makes 10 requests, how would I know if all of person A's requests have been completed 10 minutes later?

Comment: Great! Thanks for your response. I was wondering if there was a way to do it without storing user data by collecting all requests into a package from the same persistent request, but can't figure out how that would work. It is probably best to store user data.

Comment: What do you mean by "view or keep track"? Do you need to view it on terminal with something like `celery inspect`, or to display like a webpage (e.g in Administration Page)?

Comment: My goal is to provide each person who makes a request with a unique identifier in the url that when the person goes to the page, would receive one of two messages. "All of your tasks are complete" or "Your tasks are still being worked on"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your http handler fetch or define `userid`. Pass it to the task as argument. Use redis to store statistics.

```
class CallbackTask(Task):
    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        db = redis.StrictRedis(host, port)
        db.incr("succeed.tasks.user{userid}".format(**kwargs)) 
        # note: explicitly pass kwargs when schedule the task 
        # regular_task.apply_async(kwargs=dict(userid=self.get_user))

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, **kwargs, einfo):
        db = redis.StrictRedis(host, port)
        db.incr("failed.tasks.user{userid}".format(kwargs))


@app.task(base=CallbackTask)
def regular_task(foo, bar, userid):
    # do things
```

Fetch the statistics data where ever you need:

```
def get_succeed_tasks(db, userid):
    return db.get("succeed.tasks.user{userid}".format(userid=userid))
```

Comment: Wonderful thank you. I will definitely give this a try.